# Disable user printing from browser in corporate intranet

Tags: group-policy

... per a suggestion I've moved this from StackOverflow

Within a corporate intranet, can the browser be controlled via policy and/or command line parameters to prevent a user from printing a specific page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You can try to use Javascript to disable the hotkeys for printing (ctrl + p) and disable the menus with a group policy entry (it'd cause more pain than its worth), but usually that results in stopping *all* printing. Plus, savvy users can easily work around any measures put in place (like screenshotting the page and printing that).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not.

But if the web-page is under your control and your browser support for CSS is at a more or less current level, you could play with the `@media print` style sheet so the hard-copy will by white on white or something equally unprintable...

As @Nathan C said nothing prevents some of the more savvy users from printing your page, but it will throw up a minimal barrier.